# Installing specific NodeJS Version on my pi

Tags: node.js

If I want to install some specific NodeJS version from the nodejs.org/en/download or nodejs.org/dist website...do I have to take sth. in consideration?
As far as I know  the raspberrys are based on different processors, but I barely see any version in the /dist which gives me the opportunity to choose the specific processor. I don't think it's fine to pick some random tar.gz file over there.

PS: I tried to download the armv8(tar.xz), but I came across with troubles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Raspberry Pi 1 has a ARMv6 CPU with Hardware Floating Point.
- Raspberry Pi 2 has a ARMv7 CPU.
- Raspberry Pi 3 has a ARMv8 CPU.

I *think* that Raspbian Linux is still compiled for ARMv6 w/HFP, since that code will run on all three versions of the Pi, so you might need the armv6l version of NodeJS for software compatibility reasons.

Comment: I tried it right now and it worked :) thank you ! but one more question, what about the /dist? Do I have to pick the pi one? for example https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.11.11/ here

Comment: @OnlyMyRailgun The `linux-arm-pi` is the only arm version listed, so I think it's a safe bet.